# What header file needs to be included for using nullptr in g++?

Tags: g++, nullptr

I am using g++ 4.4.1 and want to use `nullptr`, but I am not being able to find which header file is required to be included. It does not seem to be keyword either, because my attempt to use it is rejected as

```
error: 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

GCC 4.4.1 does not support `nullptr`.

Support for `nullptr` was added in GCC 4.6.0:
http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.6/changes.html

> Improved experimental support for the
>   upcoming C++0x ISO C++ standard,
>   **including support for nullptr** (thanks
>   to Magnus Fromreide), noexcept,
>   unrestricted unions, range-based for
>   loops (thanks to Rodrigo Rivas Costa),
>   implicitly deleted functions and
>   implicit move constructors.

For earlier versions of GCC, if you want to experiment with `nullptr` you can try the workaround in this SO question:

[Can nullptr be emulated in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419800/can-nullptr-be-emulated-in-gcc)

Comment: since pre GCC 4.6 doesn't have nullptr you can use "__null"

Comment: @Trevor Boyd Smith:  `__null` is simply what NULL is defined to on GCC.  It is *not* the same as `nullptr`, since it (obviously) has the same semantics as NULL.  There is no reason to use `__null`.

Comment: Isn't he talking about g++?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend not using `nullptr` as defined above, because it can be dangerous.  If you want to use `nullptr` the following statement should be true.

```
sizeof(nullptr) == sizeof(void*) == sizeof(any pointer)
```

However, `sizeof(nullptr)` (as defined above) will not comply to this rule.  It will actually evaluate to `sizeof(bad nullptr) = 1`.

This is a correct implementation.

```c
#pragma once

namespace std
{
    //based on SC22/WG21/N2431 = J16/07-0301
    struct nullptr_t
    {
        template<typename any> operator any * () const
    {
        return 0;
    }
    template<class any, typename T> operator T any:: * () const
    {
        return 0;
    }

#ifdef _MSC_VER
    struct pad {};
    pad __[sizeof(void*)/sizeof(pad)];
#else
    char __[sizeof(void*)];
#endif
private:
    //  nullptr_t();// {}
    //  nullptr_t(const nullptr_t&);
    //  void operator = (const nullptr_t&);
    void operator &() const;
    template<typename any> void operator +(any) const
    {
        /*I Love MSVC 2005!*/
    }
    template<typename any> void operator -(any) const
    {
        /*I Love MSVC 2005!*/
    }
    };
static const nullptr_t __nullptr = {};
}

#ifndef nullptr
#define nullptr std::__nullptr
#endif
```

Comment: maybe you should consider also ensuring that the alignment is correct as well, if this is important to you

Comment: Yaroslav, maybe you should consider writing without shouting. :)

Answer (score 2):

I use -std=c++0x to enable the nullptr feature with gcc 4.6.3

Comment: But -std=c++0x does not enable nullptr in Gcc 4.4.x

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have the latest gcc which supports C++11 , try using NULL instead of nullptr.