# nullptr unrecognized with gcc 4.8

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

On a Red Hat Linux station, I use the devtoolset2 giving the following command:

```
scl enable devtoolset-2 bash
```

Then, when I call gcc --version, I get :

`gcc (GCC) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.`

But if I compile my program (malkefile generated with cmake, adding the line  :

```
if(UNIX)
    SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -std=c++11")
endif()
```

I have the following error message :

```
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"
```

And if I compile replacing -std=c++11 by -std=c++0x
then, I obtain these messages :

```
nullptr wasnt declared in this scope.
```

How nullptr cannot be recognized considering it is a keyword ?

I don't understand, if you have any idea...

Comment: according to [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) `nullptr` was supported since version 4.6

Comment: `cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"` <-- cc1plus isn't g++

Comment: Are you sure cmake is using the correct gcc version?

Comment: @C0deH4cker cc1plus is the compiler part of g++.

Comment: @interjay Correct. However, only the g++ compiler frontend specifically understands the `--std=c++11` flag. It converts that into arguments understood by cc1plus.

Comment: What command exactly is cmake using to invoke g++? If you're using the make backend, you may need to try something like `make V=1`  to see the commands.

Comment: @C0deH4cker: Is it not suspicious that it accepted `-std=c++0x`? I think you're wrong. I suspect the problem is that a _much_ older GCC than 4.8.2 is being invoked from CMake ([`nullptr` wasn't added until 4.6](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3756481/560648))

Comment: @C0deH4cker That isn't my experience: `$ g++ q.cpp -std=asdf` results in: `cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=asdf"`

Comment: Speculation: this might be an issue with the cmake cache, if you initially invoked cmake in a different environment (i.e. before you did `scl enable devtoolset-2 bash`)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Oops, you are correct. I made a false assertion without first checking if I was correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You are not invoking GCC 4.8.2.**

Either there is something wrong with your CMake configuration, or there is something wrong with your SCL invocation, or `gcc -v` gives a different answer to `g++ -v` (in which case, check the contents of your toolset).

But `nullptr` not being available, and `-std=c++0x` being accepted but not `-std=c++11`, all suggest GCC 4.3, 4.4 or 4.5.

One thing you can try is to remove the file `CMakeCache.txt` from your build root, which may contain cached properties of your previous environment.

Failing that, turn on verbose output so you can *really* see what's going on, what binaries are being invoked, and how.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. remve the cmake cache doesn't change anything. I tried to set CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX to true in order to make g++ run but unsuccessfully.

Comment: I tried to run verbose, setting CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE to ON, but it doesn't seem to work. Do you know exactly how we do that ? Thanks

Comment: I also need to add that in the generated Makefile, it's written VERBOSE = 1, but in the CMakeCache.txt  I have : CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=OFF and no more information about the compiler or smtg related...