# is there any way to use google test tool on gcc 4.5.2 compiler?

Tags: c++, linux, googletest, gcc4

i am use google test c++ freamwork to test my project but facing some issue  for your reference see the compilation errors as follow.

```
src/exclusions/Gtest/../../include/gtest/internal/gtest-port.h:972:37: error: ‘nullptr’ was not declared in this scope
src/exclusions/Gtest/../../include/gtest/internal/gtest-port.h:1316:22: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘override’
src/exclusions/Gtest/../../include/gtest/internal/../gtest-matchers.h:307:37: error: ‘testing::internal::MatcherBase<T>::MatcherBase(const testing::internal::MatcherBase<T>&)’ declared with non-public access cannot be defaulted in the class body
/home/buildserver/rswork25Nov/Dev-UEM-1.2-POC/src/exclusions/Gtest/../../include/gtest/internal/../gtest-matchers.h:308:48: error: ‘testing::internal::MatcherBase<T>& testing::internal::MatcherBase<T>::operator=(const testing::internal::MatcherBase<T>&)’ declared with non-public access cannot be defaulted in the class body
src/exclusions/Gtest/../../include/gtest/internal/gtest-param-util.h:521:74: error: there are no arguments to ‘InstantiationInfo’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘InstantiationInfo’ must be available
src/exclusions/Gtest/../../include/gtest/internal/../gtest-matchers.h:305:61: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘testing::internal::MatcherInterfaceAdapter<std::basic_string<char> >’
```

Comment: Please post the logs in proper format for better readability.

Comment: GCC 4.5 is quite old. Have you considered using a newer compiler? Then you could enjoy C++11/14/17 support, which your current compiler is too old to support.

Comment: @VaibhavSharma OP will have trouble formatting that properly (i.e. as code) because the system will then tell them that they need to provide more prose explanation with that much code.

Comment: You need at least gcc 4.6 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3756473/what-header-file-needs-to-be-included-for-using-nullptr-in-g/3756481#3756481

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can resort to older tag of `googletest`?

Compare `1.8.1` requirements:

```
Linux Requirements

These are the base requirements to build and use Google Test from a source package (as described below):

GNU-compatible Make or gmake
POSIX-standard shell
POSIX(-2) Regular Expressions (regex.h)
A C++98-standard-compliant compiler
```

with the latest one:

```
Build Requirements

These are the base requirements to build and use Google Test from a source package:

Bazel or CMake. NOTE: Bazel is the build system that googletest is using internally and tests against. CMake is community-supported.

a C++11-standard-compliant compiler
```

I guess you have to make a tradeoff: compatibility with your toolchain for `googletest` features.

Comment: @Dhiraj : Extra compilers are available for the most OS. Debian / Ubuntu examples https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xVEATaYAwqvseBzYxKDzJoZ4-Hc_XOJm?usp=sharing ... and Fedora / CentOS, etc. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47175706/how-to-install-gcc-4-9-2-on-rhel-7-4/47189915#47189915