# Trying to return a `std::unique_ptr` constructed with `NULL`

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm designing a Factory that creates different types of Foo and I'm trying to use smart pointers.

Most seems to be working well, but I am missing some important features (namely `nullptr`) because of compiler limitations.

I have this method:

```
std::unique_ptr<Foo> createFoo(const std::string &fooType) {
    auto it = _registeredFoo.find(fooType); // _registeredFoo is a map
    if(it != _registeredFoo.end())
       return std::unique_ptr<Foo>(it->second());
    return std::unique_ptr<Foo>(NULL);
}
```

When I test this method, it never returns a `NULL`-like pointer.

This is how I test my method.

```
std::unique_ptr<Foo> _foo = FooFactory::getInstance()->createFoo("FOO"); //FOO is registered
if(_foo) {
  std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
} else {
  std::cout << "Goodbye, World!" << std::endl;
}

std::unique_ptr<Foo> _bar = FooFactory::getInstance()->createFoo("BAR"); // BAR is unregisered
if(_bar) {
  std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
} else {
  std::cout << "Goodbye, World!" << std::endl;
}
```

I always see "Hello, World!"

This leads me to believe that my use of `std::unique_ptr`'s constructor is a bit abusive. Can anyone give me a recommendation for how to approach this without [emulating `nullptr` myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419800/can-nullptr-be-emulated-in-gcc)?

I'm using gcc 4.4.6.

Comment: Won't simply using  `unique_ptr();` help?

Comment: It's actually the same as the [default constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr). How did you check that your code _"never returns a `NULL`-like pointer"_?

Comment: _"When I test this method, it never returns a NULL-like pointer."_ This is the only part of your question that is the real question, yet it lacks detail. Can you explain your problem better?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Not _much_ surely? All you get is an additional and redundant `delete 0`, no?

Comment: "_When I test this method_..." Please show us your tests!  Perhaps your expectation is at fault rather than your code...

Comment: Edited to include my test.

Comment: After testing a little myself, I'm surprised your code compiles. Passing `NULL` (which in C++ expands to `0`) to the constructor should be ambiguous, as both a `nullptr_t` object can be constructed from the zero, as well as it could be seen as a pointer, so there are two constructors that could be used and the compiler should give you an error.

Comment: GCC 4.4.6 is old. When it says "C++0x support is experimental," it really means it. Upgrade if it's at all possible. You're living on the edge.

Comment: @Potatoswatter if only.

Comment: @erip My fallback advice is to not use C++11. You don't have a C++11 compiler. To "upgrade" the language without the underlying software is just wishful thinking.

Comment: Uh, you are aware that your code will likely lead to double-frees and/or leaked memory, especially if you get `unique_ptr` to work as it should?  You pass ownership of the pointed to memory from the registry to the `unique_ptr` you return. The `unique_ptr` will call `delete`, and your registry will probably call `delete`.  Same problem if you call `createFoo` with the same argument twice.

Comment: To break down the problem to one step at a time, directly assign an empty `unique_ptr` to `_foo` in your test: `auto foo = std::unique_ptr<Foo>(NULL);` - vary as needed.  Then we can focus on the actual problem.  With your archaic g++, we might need to `if (_foo.get())` or some such, even though that should be exactly equivalent.

Comment: @ex-bart: `it->second()` implies that `it->second` is a factory with a function call operator, and that the factory creates a brand new object. No double-frees or leaked memory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that what you want is an empty `unique_ptr`:

```
return std::unique_ptr<Foo>();
```

It seems that you are looking for a pointer that points to no object (and is `false` when converted to `bool`).

Comment: There's nothing wrong with attempting to `delete` an object at "the NULL address". Frankly I don't see why the OP's code shouldn't work.

Comment: A NULLed shared_ptr is valid, but it's hardly idiomatic.

Comment: [When I](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/aDhyaJ0yjTWKDVQ9) convert `std::unique_ptr<Foo>(NULL)` to `bool` I _do_ get false.

Comment: I really think that this, while a valid suggestion, is not a fix for the OP's problem (whatever that may be).

Answer (score 7):

You can use the default [constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr/) of `std::unique_ptr`.

```
std::unique_ptr<int> a1();
std::unique_ptr<int> a2(nullptr);
```

`a1` and `a2` are unique pointers initialised empty (owns nothing).

you can verify the emptiness of the pointers with the [operator bool](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/operator%20bool/) provided by the unique_ptr class:

```
if (!a1) { // the smart pointer is empty
}
```

Answer (score 6):

What you want is

```
return {};
```

the `{}` return a default constructed object of whatever (class) type<sup>1</sup>, and can be read "nothing".  It works with smart pointers, optional, and most everything.

If your compiler lacks this

```
return std::unique_ptr<Foo>();
```

will do it.  Passing `NULL` to `std::unique_ptr` is not legal in C++11 anyhow [(the constructor is ambiguous)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5deb751cd379c925).

You don't have a C++11 compiler.  Any use of C++11 in your code is going to be error-prone.

---

<sup>1</sup> The proper wording is [complicated](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization).  For a scalar (like `int`), this zero-initializes the value (which, in practice, sets the value to `0`/null/`0.0`/`'\0'` etc).

Comment: What was your 1 footnote going to be?

Comment: @Barry An attempt to detangle the initialization word spaghetti that C++11 left us with.  I have now included a brief attempt.