# Why is nullptr undeclared in C?

Tags: c, pointers, gcc

I am using `nullptr` becuase it is handy and makes my code more readable. But the compiler gives me error below.

My question is what **header file** must be included in order to resolve the problem.

Here a piece of code:

```
FILE *fptr;
fptr=fopen("E:\\text.txt","w");
if(fptr==nullptr)
{
   perror("open()");
   return  EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

**error**

```
 ||=== Build: Debug in 1 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
 E:\COOP\1\main.c||In function 'main':|
 E:\COOP\1\main.c|12|error: 'nullptr' undeclared (first use in this function)|
E:\COOP\1\main.c|12|note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in|
 E:\COOP\1\main.c|27|error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before
```

Comment: The brilliant accepted answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016861/why-are-null-pointers-defined-differently-in-c-and-c explains it well. Note there is no `nullptr` keyword in C.

Comment: C doesn't have a `nullptr` keyword or alias. It exists in C++ only.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419800/can-nullptr-be-emulated-in-gcc

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude But IDE gives suggestion when I enter Nu..

Comment: Then your IDE is wrong. Which IDE are you using? Which version of it?

Comment: @Ceeker: Well your IDE is being naughty in bringing C++ language into C code.

Comment: @Ceeker: Are you compiling with g++ (C++) or gcc (C)? What Some programer dude said is absolutely right. There is no `nullptr` in C it's introduced in C++11. If you're compiling with g++ you maybe have to enable features from C++11.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I use CodeBlocks 16.1 and I've downloaded GNU GCC recently and I added to IDE correctly.

Comment: Then it seems there is a bug in CodeBlocks, in that it doesn't differentiate between C and C++ sources. If you type `ne` do the IDE attempt to replace it with `new` (another C++-only keyword)? If so then the problem is probably generic and not only for one or a few keywords.

Comment: @Bathsheba When I want to write code I choose whether I want to code in C or C++. There isn't anything wrong with compiler because I see that in compiler setting C compiler is gcc.

Comment: @Some programmer dude YES IT DOES!!!!! So what am I supposed to do if I want to use only CodeBlocks? Because I am comfortable with it.

Comment: Stop being comfortable with it! How can you be comfortable with an IDE that has autocompletion that autocompletes identifiers and keywords from a **wrong** language. What next? [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)??

Comment: I would go to [their ticket system](https://sourceforge.net/p/codeblocks/tickets/) and report it as a bug. They really need to separate C and C++.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude In the early version of GCC which I used, there wasn't any suggestion when I type NU.. . Since I've upgraded it shows me suggestions both NULL and nullptr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`nullptr` is C++ only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016861/why-are-null-pointers-defined-differently-in-c-and-c); it is not needed in C because in C `((void*)0)` is convertible to any other pointer type without casts.

If you really really really like to type `nullptr` in C, you can use

```
#define nullptr ((void*)0)
```

and it would then work mostly the same.

---

Notice that C has the [`NULL`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.19p3) macro from `<stddef.h>`; it is readable too, but its expansion is implementation-defined, so it might be either `((void*)0)` or  `0` (or something really strange); if it expands to `0`, you wouldn't get any diagnostics from

```
int a = NULL;
```

Comment: @Ceeker - So does NULL. But NULL has to be defined as 0 in C++, and that causes ambiguities that nullptr solves.

Comment: @StoryTeller actually, wouldn't `#define NULL nullptr` work in C++?

Comment: @Ceeker - And as much as I like nullptr as a concept, you must use NULL if you wish for your C code to be idiomatic.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - It would work. But it's a macro that aliases a keyword, yuck.

Comment: With "((void*)0) is convertible to any other pointer type without casts.", - I have doubts this applies to function pointers.