# nullptr not declared when using -std=c++0x

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, g++, nullptr

Many other questions address similar issues, but I have yet to find an answer to this specific issue. I am getting the following error:

```
error: ‘nullptr’ was not declared in this scope
```

When compiling with the following command:

```
g++ -std=gnu++0x file1.cpp file2.cpp file3.cpp file4.cpp -o test.out
```

g++ version is 4.4.7, and unfortunately cannot be updated. Here is my system information:

```
LSB Version:    :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseWorkstation
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation release 6.9 (Santiago)
Release:    6.9
Codename:   Santiago
```

Note that my program compiles fine on MacOS High Sierra version 10.13 with the `-std=c++11` flag, which is not available on the Linux machine. I would prefer not to polyfill `nullptr` if possible.

---

#### Edit

I repeat, adding the `-std=c++0x` flag **DOES NOT WORK**. It works on MacOS, but not the Linux machine. That is the problem, and why this is not the same as similar questions I have seen on SO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can nullptr be emulated in gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419800/can-nullptr-be-emulated-in-gcc)

Comment: Did you add flag `-std=c++0x` inside Project Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> GCC C++ Compiler -> Miscellaneous?

Comment: I'm compiling from the command line, not an IDE. That flag is being used though, as the question states.

Comment: "g++ version is 4.4.7, and unfortunately cannot be updated". You can always update ;) You can install multiple versions in parallel and also in your home directory if you have no admin rights.

Comment: Null pointer constant is available in GCC 4.6 and higher. https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html

Comment: @SmitYcyken: Please do not answer in the comments section. Thank you.

Comment: @Klaus: _"You can always update"_ That's rather short sighted I'm afraid. Many (most?) programmers are not simply doing it for fun on their home systems!

Comment: For future questions, could someone please explain why this is getting downvoted?

Comment: I didn't downvote but you haven't done much research so that might be why

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit thanks, I'll put in more work next time

Comment: @treyhakanson: Good luck!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: What is the problem by using multiple compiler installations in parallel. Takes 5 or maybe 10 minutes for configure/make/install...

Comment: @Klaus: 5 or maybe 10 minutes for a compiler build? Hey, that would be nice! Regardless, time to build is not the point at all. You're making a lot of assumptions about control over the build environment, target environments, compatibility with other libraries/software, not to mention the reality that in business you need a very good reason to make changes like this (and having `nullptr` is not one of them)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I asked you already what the problem is! I can't see it. And I am wondering why others have such problems with very old compilers. So it would be nice to get an answer!

Comment: @Klaus Explaining all the myriad reasons someone who programs in real life may be compiler-constrained is well out of the scope of a SO comment. You could ask a question on SoftwareEngineering.SE though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [feature list of GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html) it clearly shows :

> Null pointer constant |  N2431 |  **GCC 4.6**

Which means that `nullptr` was implemented in GCC 4.6. GCC 4.4.7 doesn't support it yet, no flag is going to fix that. You're going to have to update your compiler if you want to use it.

Answer (score 3):

Seems that nullptr is not supported with 4.4.7 but with GCC 4.6.0: http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.6/changes.html
You could try using NULL instead of nullptr

Answer (score 2):

The specific nature of the error (the fact that it thinks it is an identifier that needs to be defined, rather than a keyword) makes it clear that your version of GCC simply doesn't support that C++11 feature.

There is no way to deal with this that doesn't involve changing compilers. You cannot effectively emulate this feature (because if you could, it wouldn't have needed to be a language feature in the first place). So if you cannot update your compiler, you cannot run code that expects all of C++11 to be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Developer Toolset (DTS)](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_developer_toolset/) to get a C++11 compiler which is compatible with the Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 system libraries.  The system compiler has very limited C++11 support only because it is too old—the first version of GCC 4.4 was released in 2009.